# I am trying to build a PowerShell object with an unknown number even number of arguments

Tags: powershell, object, arguments

I am trying to build a PowerShell object with an unknown number even number of arguments. I am using PowerShell v5 on Windows 10. My plan was to fist pass the name and then the value for each element of the new Object. I am having trouble referencing the arguments in the loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.count; $i++) {
    $NewDataObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $NewDataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name arg[$i].value -Value arg[($i+1)].value
}
```

Comment: All good, I got it working.

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.count; $i++) {

    $NewDataObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $NewDataObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $args[$i] -Value $args[($i+1)]
} 
Write-Output $args 
Write-Output $Newobject

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase `i` by 2 each iteration, or else you're setting a property of `value1` equal to `key2` at its second iteration.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.count-1; $i+=2) { ... }
```